# MySQL | REGEXP vs LIKE and character special

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

I did a search with `LIKE` and `REGEXP` a special character "ñ", the results here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testCharacter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name2` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name3` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `testCharacter` (`id`, `name`, `name2`, `name3`) VALUES
(1, 'ññ', 'ññ', 'ññ'),
(2, 'ñn', 'ñn', 'ñn'),
(3, 'nn', 'nn', 'nn');
```

**First test, `LIKE`**

```
SELECT * FROM `testCharacter` where name like '%ñ%'
```

and same result for all columns (`where name2 like '%ñ%', where name3 like '%ñ%'`) :

```
+--+-----+------+------+
|id| name| name2| name3|
+--+-----+------+------+
| 1| 'ññ'|  'ññ'|  'ññ'|
| 2| 'ñn'|  'ñn'|  'ñn'|
| 3| 'nn'|  'nn'|  'nn'|
+--+-----+------+------+
```

**Second Test, `REGEXP`**

```
SELECT * FROM `testCharacter` where name REGEXP '(ñ)'
```

and same result for all columns (`where name2 like '%ñ%', where name3 like '%ñ%'`) :

```
+--+-----+------+------+
|id| name| name2| name3|
+--+-----+------+------+
| 1| 'ññ'|  'ññ'|  'ññ'|
| 2| 'ñn'|  'ñn'|  'ñn'|
+--+-----+------+------+
```

The question, `LIKE` no have difference between characters specials (`'ñ'` and `'n'`) and `REGEXP` yes?

And applies for characters with accents, like that `á, é, í, ó, ú`

Comment: A well-known limitation of regexp support in MySQL is that it isn't multi-byte safe.

Comment: BTW, the downvote is not mine. This might be a dupe but it's clearly a question with a lot of effort. Meanwhile, horrible "Doesn't work, tried google, help!!!" questions get +4 easily.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137273/mysql-regexp-query-accent-insensitive-search