# How to search string using Entity Framework with .Contains and with accent-insensitive

Tags: c#, entity-framework, diacritics, accent-insensitive

In my database, I have a table that stores cities. Some cities have accents like "Foz do Iguaçu".

In my MVC application, I have a JSON that return a list of cities based in a word, however, few users aren't using accents to search for the city, for example "Foz do Iguacu".

in my database I have "Foz do Igua**Ç**u" but users
users searches for    "Foz do Igua**C**u"

How can I search records in my table, ignoring accents?

Here is my code:

```
    using (ServiciliEntities db = new ServiciliEntities())
    {
        List<Cidades> lCidades = db.Cidades.Where(c => c.CidNome.ToLower().Contains(q.Trim().ToLower())).OrderBy(c => c.CidNome).Take(10).ToList();
        ArrayList lNomes = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Cidades city in lCidades)
            lNomes.Add(new {city.CidNome, city.Estados.EstNome});

        return Json(new { data = lNomes.ToArray() });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName NVARCHAR (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL
```

Where LATIN1_GENERAL means English (US), CI means Case-Insensitive and AI means Accent-Insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **accent-insensitive collation** order on the column **in database**. The query then should work. For example, if you set **SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI** to the *CidNome* column, query will perform as wanted.

Use this SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName NVARCHAR (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way for doing this without change the column?

Comment: Well I don't think so actually..at the end all the Entity Framework does is translating your query to SQL..the real comparison has to do the database..if you would use some hack, it must lead to loosing the performance. So why you cant change the column?

Comment: @PetrAdam is right. This is solution to use. BTW you can configure Collation for the whole database, or in for your whole database server. The latter enable that for every database that will be created.

Comment: @Dan you can check this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054930/set-database-collation-in-entity-framework-code-first-initializer

Comment: My column is already set to COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, and that still didn't work.